# EM_UNDO does not work after programmatically writing to rich edit

Tags: winapi, sendmessage, c++builder-10-seattle

Working in C++ Builder 10 Seattle on Win7-64.

I have a TRichEdit control into which I can write from a button click event:

```
MyRichEdit->SelText = t_string;
```

I want to be able to undo that change, so I have a menu item with shortcut Ctrl+Z that does this:

```
SendMessage(MyRichEdit->Handle, EM_UNDO, 0, 0);
```

The Undo works as expected if I have *typed* into the rich edit, but not to undo the programmatically assigned "paste".

I had similar code in an old application that was built with Borland C++ Builder v6, and it works there.

My question then is: *Should* the above code undo the write-to-SelText? Or is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of the `SelText` setter looks like this:

```
procedure TCustomEdit.SetSelText(const Value: string);
begin
  SendTextMessage(Handle, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, Value);
end;
```

The documentation for `EM_REPLACESEL` says:

> **Parameters**
>
> *wParam*
>
> Specifies whether the replacement operation can be undone. If this is
>   TRUE, the operation can be undone. If this is FALSE , the operation
>   cannot be undone.
>
> *lParam*
>
> A pointer to a null-terminated string containing the replacement text.

The VCL is sending `0` which is `FALSE` and so the operation cannot be undone. You will need to avoid using `SelText` and instead send the `EM_REPLACESEL` directly, passing `TRUE` as `wParam`.

I examined the source code for the Delphi 6 VCL and it too always passes `0` for `wParam` when sending this message, so I would have expected the old versions of the VCL to behave in the same way. All the same, you now know how to resolve the issue.

As an aside, you can replace sending of `EM_UNDO` with a call to `MyRichEdit->Undo()` which does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. I should have dug down into the code myself.